# Swift: How to Convert JSON String with Alamofilre or SwiftyJSON to ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm currently using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/) for Swift for mapping JSON Object from API to model Object

but my restful api return API look like this:

```
{
       success: true,
       data: 
       [{  
          "stats":{  
             "numberOfYes":0,
             "numberOfNo":2,
             "progress":{  
                "done":false,
                "absolute":"2/100",
                "percent":2
             }
          },
          "quickStats":null,
          "uid":5,
          "name":"Flora",
          "imageArray":[  
             "http://s3.com/impr_5329beac79400000",
             "http://s3.com/impr_5329beac79400001"
          ],
          "metaData":{  
             "description":"Floral Midi Dress",
             "price":"40$"
          }
       }]

}
```

In data node is array i can't look up to mapping with this code

```
let json = JSON(responseObject!)

for tests in json["impressions"][0] {
  let test = Mapper<myTests>().map(tests)
  println(test?.impressionID)
}
```

How should I fix?
Thanks

** **Edited** **
**I found solution similar @tristan_him**

**ObjectModel mapping structure**

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var success: Bool?
    var data: [Data]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success <- map["success"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}

class Data: Mappable {
    var uid: Int?
    var name: String?
    // add other field which you want to map        

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        uid <- map["uid"]
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

**Mapping with Alamofire response**

```
let response: Response = Mapper<Response>().map(responseObject)!

for item in response.data! {
    let dataModel: Data = item
    println(dataModel.name)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can map the JSON above by using the following class structure:

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var success: Bool?
    var data: [Data]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success <- map["success"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}

class Data: Mappable {
    var uid: Int?
    var name: String?
    // add other field which you want to map        

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        uid <- map["uid"]
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

Then you can map it as follows:

```
let response = Mapper<Response>().map(responseObject)
if let id = response?.data?[0].uid {
    println(id)
}
```

Comment: @tristan_him, can we put 'Response' and 'Data' Class in two different Response.swift and Data.Swift files or we need to keep them in single .swift file?

Comment: @AshishPisey, it should work either way. That is up to you and how you want to structure your project.

Comment: is this the same for the current version and swift 3? Sorry I'm very new to this library